# Designing basic Haskell bench-marking code

Tags: haskell

I would like to write some basic bench-marking code in Haskell, namely design a function:

```
benchmark :: M a -> String -> Int -> M ()
```

which given an `action` (a monadic value with respect to my own monad `M`), a function `name` for messaging purposes, and a number of `iterations`, executes the action as many times as `iterations`, and displays a message on `stdout` about the time spent executing the code. For the purpose of this question, I assume that the monad `M` is an instance of the class `MonadIO`. In particular I have some function:

```
 liftIO :: IO a -> M a
```

Having spent many hours on 'Real World Haskell', I have been warned that "Non-strict evaluation can turn performance measurement and analysis into something of a minefield". However, I am not looking for a definitive answer, bur rather for suggestions and guidance on how best to approach this.

My naive approach is to separate the time measuring code:

```
benchmark action name iterations = do
  start <- liftIO getPOSIXTime
  runAction action iterations
  end <- liftIO getPOSIXTime
  let time = realToFrac $ (end - start) :: Double 
  liftIO $ printf "Benchmark: %s, %d iterations ran in %.3f seconds\n" 
    name iterations time
```

from the real crunch of the problem, namely that of running an `action` as a loop:

```
runAction :: Monad m => m a -> Int -> m ()
runAction action iterations
  | iterations <= 0   = return ()
  | otherwise         = do
    action
    runAction action (iterations -1)
```

The issue I have with my solution is that it seems the code spends more time in 'boiler-plate' than running the `action`: if I attempt to benchmark the simplest possible action `return ()` , I may get a time say of 1000 ms for 1 million iterations. I can see the specifics of the monad `M` play an important role (replacing `M` by `IO` would bring the time down to 250 ms instead of 1000 ms). A one million loop doing nothing may also take in the order of 250 ms in interpreted `python` or `scheme` (so the `IO` monad is not so bad), but it is a lot faster in `C`. Normally Haskell is mightily fast (not so far from `C`). I have tried a solution involving `forM` and `[1..1000000]` but without improvement.

Is there a way to approach this so the 'boiler-plate' code does not overwhelm the code being tested?

**EDIT:** The problem seemingly goes away when using the `-O2` compiler optimization option as suggested by @luqui (i.e. a one million monadic loop doing nothing has very good performance relative to other languages, at least in my case). So this question is closed as far as I can see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
runAction :: MonadIO m => m a -> Int -> m NominalDiffTime
runAction action = fmap sum . flip replicateM action'
  where
    action' = do
        start <- liftIO getPOSIXTime
        action
        end <- liftIO getPOSIXTime
        let !delta = end - start
        return delta

benchmark action name iterations = do
    time <- realToFrac <$> runAction action iterations
    liftIO $ printf "Benchmark: %s, %d iterations ran in %.3f seconds\n" 
        name iterations (time :: Double)
```

Or, you can just rewrite your `runAction`:

```
runAction = flip replicateM_
```

Or, just fix overhead:

```
time :: MonadIO m => m a -> m NominalDiffTime
time action = do
    start <- liftIO getPOSIXTime
    action
    end <- liftIO getPOSIXTime
    let !delta = end - start
    return delta

benchmark action name iterations = do
    !overhead <- time $ replicateM_ iterations (return ())
    !delta <- time $ replicateM_ iterations action
    let time = realToFrac . abs $ delta - overhead :: Double
    liftIO $ printf "Benchmark: %s, %d iterations ran in %.3f seconds\n"
        name iterations time
```

Comment: oh I can see this is clever, thank you very much ! Will try it out, give some time in case someone can beat this, and come back to validate the answer.

Comment: Simply redefining my `runAction` by `flip replicateM_` made the code about 4 times slower on my machine :(

Comment: The first version of your answer did not fulfill its promise, I think some issues may be arising from the fact that `runAction` was no longer tail recursive. I am now testing your last version

Comment: @SvenWilliamson, you're compiling with optimizations right?

Comment: @luqui Oh very sorry no, you have a specific optimization option in mind?

Comment: @luqui using -O2 does not change the timing numbers I am getting in the three code proposal I have tested so far :( Thanks v much all the same.

Comment: @freestyle I am very sorry, the first idea (based on adding times of each action call) paradoxically gives me worse numbers, (possibly because the system is stretched by solution which seems more memory intensive). As for the solution consisting of subtracting overhead (another clever idea), unfortunately I obtain very unstable numbers (possibly even negative, having removed `abs`). I feel bad you have spent time on this and I cannot yet validate the answer.

Comment: @SvenWilliamson, if you are looking for a way to accurately benchmark, which I increasingly suspect, rather than designing a benchmark system for fun, I highly recommend [criterion](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion).

Comment: @SvenWilliamson, Basically, I think problem is that you don't control or/and don't analyse GC (Garbage Collector). As wrote luqui, you can look on [criterion](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) which controls/analyses GC or [GC API](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/GHC-Stats.html) in GHC to control/analyse GC yourself.

Comment: @luqui, freestyle thank you very much, will check this out tomorrow

Comment: @luqui I don't know what I was doing wrong yesterday but the compiler option `-O2` makes  huge difference today. This is a big lesson for me. Thank you !!!

Comment: @luqui remind me to recompile dependencies when changing compiler options :)